# apt-mirror clean script isn't deleting anything

Tags: apt-mirror

I am using `apt-mirror` to create a local Ubuntu mirror. It does succeed in downloading files from another mirror (there's about a couple gigabytes each week), but never removing anything or indicates files that can be deleted. I might run out of free space, eventually.

The output of `apt-mirror` always include

> 0.0 bytes in 0 files and 0 directories can be freed.
>
> Run /var/spool/apt-mirror/var/clean.sh for this purpose.

The `clean.sh` is ran every time `apt-mirror` executes, because the content of `/var/spool/apt-mirror/var/postmirror.sh` is just

```
/var/spool/apt-mirror/var/clean.sh
```

Running `clean.sh` produces this output:

> Removing 0 unnecessary files [0 bytes]... done.
>
> Removing 0 unnecessary directories... done.

Here's my `mirror.list` file:

```
############# config ##################
#
# set base_path    /var/spool/apt-mirror
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

deb-i386 http://ubuntu.c3sl.ufpr.br/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-i386 http://ubuntu.c3sl.ufpr.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-i386 http://ubuntu.c3sl.ufpr.br/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-i386 http://ubuntu.c3sl.ufpr.br/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 

deb-amd64 http://ubuntu.c3sl.ufpr.br/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-amd64 http://ubuntu.c3sl.ufpr.br/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-amd64 http://ubuntu.c3sl.ufpr.br/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-amd64 http://ubuntu.c3sl.ufpr.br/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Solution:

Change the last line to:

```
clean http://ubuntu.c3sl.ufpr.br/ubuntu/
```

---

## Explanation:

The problem is in your last line where it defines what repository to clean. `clean` takes the name of the repository in which it should remove:

```perl
## Parse config

open CONFIG, "<$config_file" or die("apt-mirror: can't open config file ($config_file)");
while (<CONFIG>)
{
    ## Here we detect the line starting with "clean" and process the URL
    if ( $config_line eq "clean" )
    {
        $config_line[0] =~ s[^(\w+)://][];
        $config_line[0] =~ s[/$][];
        $config_line[0] =~ s[~][%7E]g if get_variable("_tilde");
        $clean_directory{ $config_line[0] } = 1;
        next;
    }
    die("apt-mirror: invalid line in config file ($.: $config_line ...)");
}
## we store the results in the "clean_directory" variable, now we will
## loop through all of them:
foreach ( keys %clean_directory )
{
    process_directory($_) if -d $_ && !-l $_;
}
## and proceed to take the actions:
sub process_directory
{
    my $dir       = shift;
    my $is_needed = 0;
    return 1 if $skipclean{$dir};
    opendir( my $dir_h, $dir ) or die "apt-mirror: can't opendir $dir: $!";
    foreach ( grep { !/^\.$/ && !/^\.\.$/ } readdir($dir_h) )
    {
        my $item = $dir . "/" . $_;
        $is_needed |= process_directory($item) if -d $item && !-l $item;
        $is_needed |= process_file($item)      if -f $item;
        $is_needed |= process_symlink($item)   if -l $item;
    }
    closedir $dir_h;
    push @rm_dirs, $dir unless $is_needed;
    return $is_needed;
}
```

The directories where the files are stored are in the form of `/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/mirror.domain`, so to decide what directories to clean, it should match any of these directories, if it doesn't then do nothing.

That's why changing the url to match the others is the solution.

Comment: if i have wheezy and  jessie  under the same url how do i delete only one of them without affecting the other ?  :                  http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian wheezy main   |       http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main

Comment: @AsafMagen what are you doing exactly? If you don't want wheezy on your mirror, simply don't list it.

Comment: im hosting debian 7 and debain 8 repo and now i dont need 7 anymore and want to free up the space its packages are taking. so simly remove it from apt-mirror.list will free the space ?